# How to grep specific lines from nmap -O output?

Tags: text, sed, awk, grep, nmap

I got many files named like `192.168.203.txt` as the output of

```
sudo nmap -O --top-ports 192.168.203.* >>192.168.203.txt
```

The output looks like as below:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.203.29
Host is up (0.00067s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp   closed   ftp
22/tcp   closed   ssh
23/tcp   closed   telnet
25/tcp   closed   smtp
80/tcp   open     http
110/tcp  closed   pop3
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
443/tcp  closed   https
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
3389/tcp filtered ms-wbt-server
Device type: general purpose
Running: Microsoft Windows 2008|7
OS CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2008::sp2 cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_7
OS details: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 SP2, Microsoft Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 SP1
Network Distance: 6 hops
```

I just want to grep the IP like `192.168.203.29` with `http` or `ssh` or other ports  `open` sepetately. Maybe I will pipe all the result `IP` into a file named `http_open_ip.txt`.

I have tried grep `ftp` with commands:

```
cat *.txt|grep -B 3 "ftp"|grep -B3 "open"|grep "192.168."|awk '{print $5}'|sort -t . -k 3,3n -k  4,4n> ftp_open_ip.txt
```

Thus, I got a file `ftp_open_ip.txt`. But I found this command  not work with other keywords like `ssh` `stmp`. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly clear about what you want. Perhaps, you want to look in all the files and for all those IP which will have a http port open in one file, ssh port open in another file. So same IP may be present in multiple files.
Assuming that, below is an `awk` solution

```
awk 'BEGIN{http_open="http_open";ssh_open="ssh_open";ftp_open="ftp_open"}
  /Nmap scan report for/{ip=$5}
  /ftp/ && /open/{print "ftp open for " ip >> ftp_open}
  /ssh/ && /open/{print "ssh open for " ip >> ssh_open }
  /http/ && /open/{print "http open for " ip >> http_open}
  ' <filename>
```

It assumes that the file is containing data in same order shown in your example. So `Nmap scan report for` line has the IP in 5th field. Now after that, the rest is really simple. if ftp, ssh, http etc are found along with `open` status, we redirect the output in corresponding file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all this challenging text processing, you should use Nmap's own features that make this kind of output processing easier. First, Nmap offers many [output formats](http://nmap.org/book/man-output.html), and options to output to files. Start with this command:

```
sudo nmap -oA my-scan-%y%m%d -O --top-ports 192.168.203.0/24
```

The `-oA my-scan-%y%m%d` option will save the output of your scan in 3 different files:

```
$ ls
my-scan-20130520.gnmap   my-scan-20130520.nmap   my-scan-20130520.xml
```

For quick queries, the [.gnmap](http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) file will be the easiest to use with `awk` or `grep`, but it doesn't have all the useful information that is included in the normal (.nmap) or [XML formats](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/docs/nmap.dtd). If you plan to make this script automated, or extend it in any way, your best bet will be to use the XML output.

Here are a couple commands that will do what you want with these output formats:

```
awk '/\/open\/tcp\/\/http\//{print $2}' my-scan-*.gnmap > http_open_ip.txt

xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//port[@protocol='tcp' and service/@name='ssh' and state/@state='open']/ancestor::host/address[@addrtype='ipv4']" -v '@addr' -n my-scan-*.xml > ssh_open_ip.txt
```